# R error while using POSIXct

Tags: r, excel, csv

this is my data and i want to import them so when i execute this command

```
  data.raw=read.csv(file=file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names=NULL)%>%
  mutate(date.re = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

i get the following error

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  c("do not know how to convert 'function (x) ' to class “POSIXct”", "do not know how to convert 'UseMethod(\"date\")' to class “POSIXct”")
```

here's my data thank you in advance
[data](https://1fichier.com/?8gsvdd1l68)

Comment: Without the data it's difficult, but what's date? If it's the column name, try data$date instead, if not: no idea!

Comment: I'm not downloading some random link. Paste the first few rows of your file, including the column headers, into the question.

Comment: the data is here: https://1fichier.com/?8gsvdd1l68

Comment: Like I said, I'm not downloading some random link. Paste your data into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
data.raw=read.csv(file=file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=";",row.names=NULL)%>%
mutate(date.re = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

**sep** is different ";"